# Uniform closures are uniformly closed but pointwise closures might not be pointwise closed

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

An old set of classroom notes I took in a math course says the following:

> For a set ${X}$ let $\mathcal{A}$ be a set of functions from $X$ to
>   $\mathbb{R}$.  Then
>
> 1. the uniform closure of $\mathcal{A}$ is uniformly closed.
> 2. the pointwise closure of $\mathcal{A}$ is not necessarily
>      pointwise closed.

The prof said the first assertion was straightforward (we proved it as homework) but that the second was not (I came up with a counter-example).

I'd like to write up the counter-example in a short note, but I don't even know what field of math this is in.  Topology?  Real analysis?  Specifically, I'd like some easily accessed (preferably online) citations that discuss and give background to these assertions. So far my online searches have landed on discussions that assume the functions form an algebra, or have restrictions such as boundedness or continuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suitable context for discussion of the assertions is the concept of [Baire functions and Baire classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_function).  Quoting from the linked article:

> Baire functions of class α, for any countable ordinal number α, form a
>   vector space of real-valued functions defined on a topological space,
>   as follows.
>
> - The Baire class 0 functions are the continuous functions.
> - The Baire class 1 functions are those functions which are the    pointwise limit of a sequence of Baire class 0 functions.
> - In general, the Baire class α functions are all functions which are    the pointwise limit of a sequence of functions of Baire class less
>     than α.

So, if $\mathcal{A}$ is the set of continuous functions, its pw(pointwise) closure is the set of Baire class 1 functions, and the pw closure of that is the set of Baire class 2 functions, etc.  In other words, the pw closure of $\mathcal{A}$ is not pw closed.

Coming up with more restricted examples of $\mathcal{A}$ is another problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is topology within real analysis and covered by, for example, "Baby Rudin" Principles of Mathematical Analysis, Walter Rudin, page 144 in the 3rd edition.
You also need the concept of a Banach space with the "point-wise" max norm. See the table of classical Banach spaces, specifically C(X) here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space
and here
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_functions_on_a_compact_Hausdorff_space

Comment: Yes, the concepts of `uniform closure` and `uniformly closed` are defined, but not much more.  Neither (1) nor (2) in my original question is addressed, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Examples 7.2-7.6 on the following pages in Rudin are examples of pointwise convergent sets of continuous functions whose pointwise limits are not continuous.

Comment: Assertion 2 has nothing to do with preservation of properties like continuity, differentiability, etc, so at first glance none of these additional references address the question directly.  Nevertheless, these are good pointers into the general subject area (I remember names like Baire and Banach being mentioned in the class).  I suspect that Assertion 2 may be somewhere in that literature, but I have yet to find it.

Comment: As a wild guess (I know next to nothing about this topic), I would say that Assertion 2 would pertain if $\mathcal{A}$ contained functions in higher Baire classes.